# Turn string in dict error - unexpected character after line continuation character - python

Tags: python, dictionary, os.walk

**The Problem:**

I am trying to turn a string into a dictionary, so I can try to merge it with my other dictionary. However when I try to use the eval() command, it gives an error `unexpected character after line continuation character (<string>, line 1)`

**The Goal:**

My goal is to add the path of my mp4s to my metadata dictionary so I can then insert the data into sqlite all in one shot.

Here is my code to get the paths I want:

```
import os
import subprocess
##from tinytag import TinyTag #that is to pull metadata from my mp4s

def playmusic(name):
    count = 0
    extf = ['$RECYCLE.BIN','System Volume Information']
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'\\Vgmstation\\e\\', followlinks=True):
        dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in extf]
        for file in files:
            if name in file and file.endswith(".mp4"):
                vlc='C:/Program Files/VideoLAN/VLC/vlc.exe'
                music=str(os.path.join(file))
                musicpath=str("{"+'path: '+'+(os.path.join(root,file)+'+'}'))
                musicpath_dict = eval(musicpath)
##              tm = TinyTag.get(musicpath)
##              tmd = tm.duration
                musiconly= os.path.splitext(music)[0]
                print(musicpath)
                count = count + 1 
                if count == 5:
                    break
        if count >= 5:
            break
    print("Finish")
    input()
try:
    s=raw_input("name: ")
    playmusic(s)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    print("Error")
```

Here is the result of the code ran above:

```
name: m
{path: \\Vgmstation\\e\\Dreamcast\Dead or Alive 2\27 Unknown.mp4}
{path: \\Vgmstation\\e\\Dreamcast\Dead or Alive 2\28 Unknown.mp4}
{path: \\Vgmstation\\e\\Dreamcast\Dead or Alive 2\Blazed Up Melpomene.mp4}
{path: \\Vgmstation\\e\\Dreamcast\Dead or Alive 2\Bomb Factory - Exciter.mp4}
{path: \\Vgmstation\\e\\Dreamcast\Dead or Alive 2\Bomb Factory - Exciter2.mp4}
Finish
```

Here is my code to try and turn the path into a dict:

```
##code from above
musicpath_dict = eval(musicpath)
#code from above
```

Here is the result if I print `musicpath_dict` :

```
name: m
unexpected character after line continuation character (<string>, line 1)
Error
```

I believe the problem is my slashes that I have in the string, but I need thoses there exactly as they are. The goal is to add a path row to my sqlite database so I can pull the file's location to play the song later down the road. (If that makes sense)

If anyone has any suggestions or ideas, let me know.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Those \ characters *all* need to be doubled up, or for example `\27` will be interpreted as some character you didn't expect.

Comment: That makes sense, but I have no clue how to add that extra slashes to the results since its a variable output result. I may try to see if there is some string formatting where I can add another slash from a variable.

Comment: Actually, I had that backwards.  Since you're using `print` to print a `str`, the doubled up backslashes are the odd ones.  I don't know why that would cause an error though.

Comment: Now I think I see it - you're using `eval` to create a dict.  Don't do that.  You haven't quoted the string you're using as the value, so weird things are happening.

Comment: I need to use eval to create a dict from the path of the mp4. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-create-a-dictionary-from-a-string/ The `("{"+'path: '+'+(os.path.join(root,file)+'+'}'))` is just my attempt at making the string look like a dictionary so the eval can it into one. (If that makes sense). Unless there is another way to turn the string into a dictionary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `eval` to create a variable, ever.  It could lead to bugs and is completely unnecessary.  You can get what you want by creating a dictionary directly:

```
musicpath_dict = {'path': os.path.join(root,file)}
```

Comment: That is so much easier than I thought I didn't know you can just make the dictionary from the variable directly like this!